# Eclipse/Maven and "Resolve dependencies from workspace projects" can't mix jars and source?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I've got what seems like a corner case for Eclipse/Maven and "Resolve dependencies from workspace projects". My project has a mix of written code and generated code, with the generated code coming from a dependency which uses JAXWS.

The problem is that if I check "Resolve dependencies", Eclipse/Maven ignores any JAR dependencies and tries to resolve everything by only looking at the workspace, which results in Eclipse showing errors like "Package/Class not found" (related to the generated code) even though the project will build fine with Maven from the command line.

On the other hand, if I uncheck it, it resolves everything by only looking at the JARs in the Maven repository. The second option generally works, but when I do something like Ctrl-click on a class or variable, I get the Class File Editor and "Source not found", which isn't terribly useful. Also, it can get out of sync if I edit code in the IDE but don't run "maven install" after that.

I suppose this is mainly an inconvenience with Eclipse but it's annoying. I am considering resolving this by modifying the Maven dependencies to build with source (or debug) but I can't necessarily do this with everything. Is the "Resolve dependencies" option intended to work exclusively one way or the other as I've described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the build helper maven plugin.

You can configure it like this :

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-sources</source>
                                <source>target/jaxws/wsimport/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

This will tell your eclipse maven plugin to have a look at the generated sources and include it in your project classpath.

You can also add the generated sources manually to your classpath in eclipse. (right-click on the generated folder -> add to build path)

Comment: For those unable to find the "add to build path" option in their context menu for a folder: in my case (Eclipse Luna), it's under `Build Path` -> `Use as Source Folder`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that since you want to reference files that only exist after a build that you somehow force the build to happen before you need the references resolved.  You could cheat by just doing a build from within Eclipse.  That would leave the generated source files in place ready to be referenced.  I think, however, that the maven philosophy would have you move the generated code to another maven artifact entirely.  That would let you separate the lifecycle of the two groups of code so that when you're ready to use Eclipse to edit the hand-coded code, references to generated classes are resolved because you've already generated that code in the build of an separate, independent module.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue. But I encountered the same thing in Juno with an updated "m2e-wtp" plugin. So I'm answering solely for other readers' benefit.

This was only happening in war projects. The only thing resolved it eventually was removing the ".settings" folder under the war project's folder and restarting eclipse.